# How to get real count of a CollectionView, when Filter is in use?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, collectionview

When I have a `<Label Content="{Binding ItemCount}"/>` on my View to bind to a property on the ViewModel.

On the viewmodel I have the property defined as

```
public int ItemCount
{
    get { RowViewModelsCollectionView.Count; }
}
```

I am clearly asking for count on the `CollectionView`, where I am expecting to get the count of only visible items. Unfortunately I get the count of the entire rows, even the ones not showing on the view due the filter.

**Update:**

**in Ctor:**

```
RowViewModelsCollectionView= new ListCollectionView(rowViewModels) {Filter = Contains};


private bool Contains(object obj)
        {
            RowViewModel rowViewModel = obj as RowViewModel;

            if (rowViewModel != null && Books.ContainsKey(rowViewModel.Book))
            {
                RaisePropertyChanged("ItemCount"); // Trying out to raise it without joy
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
```

How should I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623736/filtered-collectionview-gives-wrong-count How do you get the CollectionView?

Comment: Its not a duplicate. The solution there is using a GetDefaultView(). We can't do this in our app due the nature of requirements.

Comment: Well maybe because you don't use GetDefaultView you always recreate a new view, thus on one you have the filter, but you use the other to get the count.

Comment: I don't think so. Please have a look at the updated code, if it makes sense, otherwise I am happy to change the code. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't you use this?

```
<Label Content="{Binding ModelView.RowViewModelsCollectionView.Count}"/>
```

This is a little example.

```
<Window x:Class="WPFValidation.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window"
        Height="300"
        Width="300">
  <Grid>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBox Grid.Row="0"
             Text="{Binding FilterText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
               Text="{Binding ModelListView.Count}" />
    <ListBox Grid.Row="2"
             ItemsSource="{Binding ModelListView}" />

  </Grid>
</Window>

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WPFValidation
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public MainWindow() {
      this.DataContext = new ModelView();
      this.InitializeComponent();
    }
  }

  public class ModelView : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private ICollectionView modelListView;

    private ICollection<string> collection;

    public ModelView() {
      this.collection = new ObservableCollection<string>(new[] {"test1", "test2", "filtering"});
    }

    public ICollectionView ModelListView {
      get { return this.modelListView ?? this.GetModelListView(); }
    }

    private ICollectionView GetModelListView() {
      var collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.collection);
      collectionView.Filter += o => o == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.FilterText) || o.Equals(this.FilterText);
      return collectionView;
    }

    private string filterText;

    public string FilterText {
      get { return this.filterText; }
      set {
        if (value != this.filterText) {
          this.filterText = value;
          this.ModelListView.Refresh();
          this.RaisePropertyChange("FilterText");
        }
      }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChange(string propertyName) {
      var eh = this.PropertyChanged;
      if (eh != null) {
        eh(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, How is this meant to be working? The CollectionView must be accessed through a property on the viewmodel.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but what's the problem if there is such a property?

Comment: If your query is changed, then you must call RowViewModelsCollectionView.Refresh();

Answer (score 5):

@punker76, is correct in saying that binding should be done to the collection view's `Count` property directly...

Reason is that `CollectionView` has implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` and notifies property changes for its `Count` property whenever commit, filtering, grouping, sorting takes place on it...

So assuming that you have `RowViewModelsCollectionView` as a public / internal property of your view model,

```
  <Label Content="{Binding RowViewModelsCollectionView.Count}"/>
```

.... should work just fine...